# bubble sort on link list is removing elements during swap

Tags: c, linked-list, bubble-sort

current uni student and i am trying to sort a link list by only swapping the links and not the data ( as per requirements)

my link definition is:

```
typedef struct iorb {
        int base_pri;
        struct iorb *link;
        char filler[100];
} IORB;
```

I am building the list like so:

```
void buildList(IORB **h, int size,int(*prio)(int)){
    int counter = size;
        // loop will run until the size of the list is reached 
        while(size > 0){ 
                IORB *temp = (IORB*)malloc(sizeof(IORB)); //alocating memory on the stack for the link list
                temp->base_pri = (rand() % 100); // assigning random number as the base pointer
                sprintf(temp->filler, "request %d : base priority = %d : priority = %d \n",
                counter, temp->base_pri,(*prio)(temp->base_pri));
                temp->link = *h; // making sure the head points to the next item in the list.
                *h = temp;
                counter--;
                size--;
                
        }
}
```

and this is my sort function:

```
void sortList(IORB* head,int (*prio)(int)){
    int swapped = 1;

    while(swapped)
    {
        //pointers for the last current and next node
        IORB **prev = &head, *curr, *next;

        swapped = 0;
        for(curr = head; curr; prev = &curr->link, curr = curr->link)
        {
            next = curr->link;

            if(next && (*prio)(curr->base_pri) > (*prio)(next->base_pri))
            {
                curr->link = next->link;
                next->link = curr;
                *prev = next;

                swapped = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

priComp is an additional function defined as:

```
int priComp(int bs){
    return (bs * 3);
}
```

and to display the list:

```
void displayList(IORB* head){
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s",head->filler);
        head = head->link;
        
    }
    
}
```

the problem I am having:
after building the list and using the display function I can correctly see the list
but after I call the sort function and reprint the list sometimes the list will print sorted but majority of the time I will be missing elements

for example -

**before sort:**

```
request 1 : base priority = 10 : priority = 30
request 2 : base priority = 3 : priority = 9
request 3 : base priority = 53 : priority = 159
```

**after sort:**

```
request 2 : base priority = 3 : priority = 9
request 1 : base priority = 10 : priority = 30
```

the list fails to print request 3. (it is not always the last element it skips but sometimes will skip an element in the middle of the list)

When i run the sort function through the debugger I can not pinpoint when the links are either being lost or removed. the loops and if statements seem to be flowing correctly.

Comment: You by-value argument for `head` is screwing the algorithm. Suggest you change it to `IORB **head`, change `IORB **prev = head`, and finally `for(curr = *head;...`. The caller, of course, needs to pass the address of the head pointer as well.

Comment: forget to mention the function declaration needs to stay the same, i can not change it to **head

Comment: @william_ Function declaration needs to stay the same : OK. But, could you modify the function body ?

Comment: yeah the function body is what i came up with, i just have to use void sortList(IORB* head,int (*prio)(int))

Comment: @william_. I have a solution but very very ugly. So, I insist : Are you sure, you could not change the function prototype as suggested by WhozCraig ?

Comment: The caller of your function will never know what the new head is of the sorted list. You  must change the signature of your function, or it will just not be possible.

Comment: I shall confirm with my marker about changing the function prototype. What changes would be made to the body if that was the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested above in comments by trincot and WhozCraig, your list is sorted but the problem comes from the fact you have not the new head.
I answer to your question with an ugly workaround because it seems that you could not change the function prototype. But, I insist it is not a good solution.

The null pointer of last list element is used to get back the head of the list.

First, add theses lines to the end of `sortlist` function.

```
IORB *curr;
for(curr = head; curr->link; curr = curr->link);
curr->link=head;
```

**!!!!!!!!! DO NOT USE SORTLIST DIRECTLY. NOW, YOU HAVE AN INFINITE LOOP LIST !!!!**

But call this function : `uglyWorkaround(&mylist,priComp);`

```
uglyWorkaround(IORB** mylist,int (*prio)(int))
{
    sortList(*mylist,priComp);

    IORB *curr = *mylist;    
    while(!((*prio)(curr->base_pri) > (*prio)(curr->link->base_pri)))
        curr = curr->link;
    *mylist=curr->link;
    curr->link=NULL;
}
```

*** Edit : To answer to comment about *clarification* on function prototype ***

The WhozCraig solution

```
void sortList2(IORB** head,int (*prio)(int)){
    int swapped = 1;

    while(swapped)
    {
        //pointers for the last current and next node
        IORB  **prev=head, *curr, *next;

        swapped = 0;
        for(curr = *head; curr; prev = &curr->link, curr = curr->link)
        {
            next = curr->link;

            if(next && (*prio)(curr->base_pri) > (*prio)(next->base_pri))
            {
                curr->link = next->link;
                next->link = curr;
                *prev = next;

                swapped = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And to call it : `sortList2(&mylist,priComp);`

Comment: this solutions works, im just clarifying about changing the function prototype
could you please explain what you did for the solution please

Comment: @william_. `void sortList(IORB** head,int (*prio)(int))` and after you have to change your function body as suggested by WhozCraig. The problem is that you do not change the head pointer of your list and you could not with your function prototype (see trincot comment). So the first element in your sorted list is the same than in the unsorted list and you loose the element that are before.